# ASP.NET File.Copy Throws Declaration Expected error

Tags: asp.net, compilation, copy, declaration

This is my first time ever doing anything in ASP.NET, so I'm probably doing something incredibly stupid to an experienced ASP.NET developer.

Here's the situation:  I have many files which are just named a GUID without a file extension.  At times I want to render these in a web browser.  This is all working fine if I manually rename the files with a `.pdf` file extension.  I'm trying to write a script in ASP.NET to copy the file to add the extension when it's requested.  Here's my code:

```
<script runat="server">
dim guid = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("file")

dim path =  HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
dim origin = path + guid
dim destination = origin + ".pdf"

System.IO.File.Copy(origin, destination)
</script>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var htmldata = "<embed src='http://myurl.com/<%=guid%>.pdf' style='width:100%; height:100%;'>";
    document.getElementById('pdf').innerHTML = htmldata;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="pdf"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

This throws the following error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to 
service this request. Please review the following specific error details and 
modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30188: Declaration expected.

Source Error:
Line 6:  dim destination = origin + ".pdf"
Line 7:  
Line 8:  System.IO.File.Copy(origin, destination)
Line 9:  </script>
Line 10: <html>
C:\path\to\web\root\default.aspx(8) Line: 8 

Show Detailed Compiler Output:
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> REALLY LONG LINE THAT I'LL INCLUDE IF NEEDED
Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 10.0.30319.233
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
C:\path\to\web\root\default.aspx(8) : error BC30188: Declaration expected.
System.IO.File.Copy(origin, destination)
~~~~~~
```

Comment: Did you try my edited code? It should fix the second edit problem. Just move filename outside the Page_Load ;)

Comment: I had apparently refreshed the page before your edited code was posted.  I took out the edits to my post to make sure the question/answer was clear.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, using guid as a variable name threw an error about "guid is a type" or something.  So I changed the variable name to filename rather than guid.

Comment: Makes sense. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code is correct, but I don't see this inside any function. I suppose you want this inside the `Page_Load` event:

```
<script runat="server">
    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim guid = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("file")

        Dim path = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
        Dim origin = path + guid
        Dim destination = origin + ".pdf"

        System.IO.File.Copy(origin, destination)
    End Sub
</script>
```

**EDIT**: If you want access to the `filename` variable, that needs to go outside the Page_Load and be a public variable like this:

```
Public filename As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("file")
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load ...
```

Comment: I don't have anything called Form1.  Will this still work?  I changed my code a bit.  I'll edit the question to show this.